# How to Install Windows8 with Ubuntu on laptop?

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, ubuntu-12.04, windows-installation

In my laptop, I have installed Windows 7 with Ubuntu 12.04LTS. Now I need to replace Windows 7 with Windows 8 without formatting Ubuntu. Is it possible to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.Install.. Windows 8 in  the same partition of windows 7 by formatting that partition alone .

2 .  Now when you  restart or switch on your laptop,you will be directed automatically to windows 8.

3.insert a **ubuntu live  bootabe disk**.

4.give try ubuntu  and install boot-repair tool in ubuntu

5.refer this link

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair[1]

6.open it and give fix automatically

7.it will install a fresh grub loader and it will detect your windows installation automatically

8.Now restart your system.. you can see both windows 8 loader and ubuntu in grub menu

feel free to post your doubts below

Comment: let me try this

Comment: it's working. thx.